# What do the feature maps and gradients mean in a UNet?

Tags: python, gradient

I have the feature map values and gradient map values for each layer in a UNet, but I'm not sure what they represent with respect to how the UNet is removing noise from an image? Is the feature map providing information about where in the image the layers are focusing on? Is the gradient map revealing how each layer is adjusting to determine what information is important?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.